# Xcode 6 GM Seed iOS 8 Simulator

Tags: xcode, ios8

When I try to run my app on iOS Simulator (iOS 8.0) it shows only the default launch image which is a white background and a text with my project name and at the bottom the copyright. What should I do to run my app when I press the compile button?

Comment: Running app is same as it was in xcode 5

Comment: @Bhumit is right same thing as before. Check for any unintended code in `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`. Additionally, download the 7.1 (or 7.0 if preferred) simulator to check if results are similar.